# Error: Program type already present: com.marcohc.robotocalendar.BuildConfig

Tags: android, class, duplicates

I have been dealing with this error for days now, and have reviewed all the other related questions. So thought I'd come and ask for help. Will post anything necessary.

(app)build.gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.gfitsolutions"
        minSdkVersion 16 //needs 16 instead of 15 for Auth
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation project(':library')
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.0-beta2'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore:21.1.1'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:19.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.media:media:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.marcohc:robotocalendarview:3.6.1'
    implementation 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.3.0'
    implementation 'pl.pawelkleczkowski.customgauge:CustomGauge:1.0.4'
    implementation group: 'org.apache.commons', name: 'commons-lang3', version: '3.9'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13-beta-3'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0-alpha02'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0-alpha02'
    implementation 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
    implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.9.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0-beta04'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
}
```

It is unclear to me where the duplication occurs. It seems when the app tries to build, the marco calendar class generates a 'BuildConfig' class identical to my app's BuildConfig class, causing the duplication error. If I am wrong in this please let me know. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Link is an image showing duplicate BuildConfig classes when searching:

[link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rypzi.png)

Answer (score 0):

So, after tons of testing I figured out the solution to my problem. Incase anyone is dealing with this, it isn't the BuildConfig file but the a duplicate dependency. My app was crashing when removing either, but after fixing my code I was able to remove one.
implementation 'com.github.marcohc:robotocalendarview:3.6.1'
was part of:
:library
so had to be removed.